# No data published on /velodyne_points from Velodyne VLP16 Lidar

Tags: ip, robotics, ros2, lidar, husky

I have plugged the VLP16 using the Ethernet cable (and set it's IP to 192.168.1.110 with a netmask of 255.255.255.0) to a Husky robot and plugged it to a power source to turn it on. I ran the `ros2 launch velodyne velodyne-all-nodes-VLP16-launch.py` which should launch all the needed nodes. When I echo the /velodyne_points which should pass the point cloud data I get no response.
But when i plug in the Lidar's Ethernet (same IP and netmask) to my computer and follow the exact same steps I can see data being published to the /velodyne_points topics and am able to visualize it in RViz2.

Why would it not work on the Husky?

I tried to ssh to the Husky from my computer expecting it was a wiring issue or some thing of the sort but it did not work.
The `ros2 launch velodyne velodyne-all-nodes-VLP16-launch.py` works and I get the message that the data is being passed but when I echo the topic directly from the husky it gives me no data. So I know data is being sent but not received.